# How to create environment variables in google cloud?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have created and `Express js` server and deployed it to google cloud. To connect to the database I am using `dotenv` file that is located outside of the project directory and it works fine on `localhost`.

For the deployed app on google cloud I have created within the project directory a file called `env_variables.yaml` (added to `.gitignore`) as follow:

```
env_variables:
  MONGODB_URI: 'uri-to-the-data-base'
```

and modified the `app.yaml` as follow:

```
includes:
  - env_variables.yaml

runtime: nodejs20
```

When I deploy the app to google clould and the `env_variables` file is inside the project dir it works fine. However, I prefer not to have it inside my project. Is there a way to create that file inside google cloud platform directly in a way that the deployed app can use it?

I tried the following:

I moved the `env_variables.yaml` file to a different directory and tried to create a secret in google cloud by importing the file there and gave permission to the `App Engine default service account` "principle" by assigning the `Secret Manager Secret Accessor` role it. Then in the `app.yaml` tried removing the `includes: - env_variables.yaml` line but that didn't help, and when I kept it, it gave an error because I moved the `env_variables.yaml` file to a different dir.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried looking into adding env vars to GAE [using cloud build](https://medium.com/@brian.young.pro/how-to-add-environmental-variables-to-google-app-engine-node-js-using-cloud-build-5ce31ee63d7)? It stores the env vars in a cloud build trigger. It will then be used during one of its build steps.